# PYSPARK - Reading, Converting and splitting a EBCDIC Mainframe file into DataFrame

Tags: ascii, apache-spark-sql, mainframe, pyspark

We have an **EBCDIC Mainframe format file** which is already loaded into **Hadoop HDFS** Sytem. The File has the Corresponding **COBOL structure** as well. We have to Read this file from HDFS, Convert the file data into *ASCII format* and need to **split the data** into *Dataframe* based on its COBOL Structure. I've tried some options which didn't seem to work. Could anyone please suggest us some proven or working ways.

Comment: Does it have comp variables in it? Or it just have alphanumeric and numeric values.. can you provide a sample file with respective copybook structure to break it.?

Comment: If it has some comp or packed decimal fields then best way to do conversion at Mainframe source itself.. rest decoding it into csv can be done using some script probably in java or python.. if you are allowed to use external jars or lib then there are some on net..

Comment: I would suggest the Mainframe dataset be converted from EBCDIC to ASCII using DFSORT's ```TRAN=ETOA``` option provided if the dataset doesn't have packed or binary fields. The converted dataset can then be imported to Hadoop HDFS system.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the copybook?  Specifically the data types.

Answer (score 0):

For python, take a look at the Copybook package (https://github.com/zalmane/copybook). It supports most features of Copybook includes REDEFINES and OCCURS as well as a wide variety of PIC formats.

```
pip install copybook
root = copybook.parse_file('sample.cbl')
```

For parsing into a PySpark dataframe, you can use a flattened list of fields and use a UDF to parse based on the offsets:

```
offset_list = root.to_flat_list()
```

disclaimer : I am the maintainer of https://github.com/zalmane/copybook

Answer (score -1):

Find the COBOL Language Reference manual and research functions DISPLAY-OF and National-Of. The link : https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-convert-ebcdic-ascii-or-ascii-ebcdic-cobol-program.